# How to confirm password in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to confirm user password in a secure way using PasswordInput() but Django seem to only allow for one PasswordInput() per form.  What is the best way to implement confirm_password below:

```
class VerifyAccountsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username'}), label="")
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'}), label="")
    password_verify = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Verify password'}), label="")

    def clean_password(self):
        print self.cleaned_data
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password_verify')
        if not password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("You must confirm your password")
        if password1 != password2:
        raise forms.ValidationError(_('Your passwords do not match'), code='invalid') 
        return password2
```

The output of clean_data is only the username and password, no password_verify.

Answer (score 0):

if you use django's own usercreationform, you can have both fields, [here is how I used it](http://www.django-tips.com/tip/reuse-djangos-register-form-if-you-dont-have-your-own-huge-number-of-register-fields/22/)

form's `clean_password2()` function compares two password inputs and validates them too, and [returns the second password](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L81).

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to implement this without using a model but still implement it securely?

Comment: @HC sure, you can do it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what gives you the idea that Django only allows one password input per form. You can have as many as you like, Django won't stop you.

Note that your current code is called on validation of password, but returns the value of password_verify.

However if you're getting something you don't expect from cleaned_data, you should post the code of the clean method.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `def clean_password(self):` to `def clean_password2(self):` in
the forms.py and in HTML registration form(registraton.html) write `{{ form.password2.errors.as_text }}` just above the password input field.